# refactoring and using a counter?

Tags: php, refactoring

I have the following structure:

```
$text_1 = $this->getValue('value_1');
$text_2 = $this->getValue('value_2');
$text_3 = $this->getValue('value_3')
```

And also the following:

```
    foreach($text_1 as $t_1)
    {
        if(!$first)
        {
            $string_1 .= ",";

        }
        $first = false;
        $string_1 .= $t_1;
    }

    foreach($text_2 as $t_2)
    {
        if(!$first)
        {
            $string_2 .= ",";

        }
        $first = false;
        $string_2 .= $t_2;
    }

    foreach($text_3 as $t_3)
    {
        if(!$first)
        {
            $string_3 .= ",";

        }
        $first = false;
        $string_3 .= $t_3;
    }
```

I was wondering if this could be re-factored to use a counter, like in a for loop, to replace the _1, _2, _3 etc from my code?

Comment: What is in `$text_1` and what are you doing? Almost looks like a custom `implode()`.

Comment: $text_1 is an array that holds data belonging to a form field. The array holds data on which of the forms checkboxes have been checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out a way of doing it:

```
    for ($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) {
         $choices = $this->getValue('question_'.$i);

         $serialized = "";
         $first = true;

         foreach($choices as $choice)
         {
            if(!$first)
            {
                $serialized .= ",";
            }
            $first = false;
            $serialized .= $choice;
        }

        $this->setValue('question_'.$i, $serialized);

     }
```

This seems to work well!

Comment: You can still replace the entire `foreach` loop with `implode`, absolutely no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the foreach-loops can be replaced with [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Other than that, wouldn't it be better to use an array for your `$text_??` variables? Eg.:

```
$text = $this->getValue('value');
foreach ($text as $value) {
  $strings[] = implode(",", $value);
}
```

Hard to give more concrete advise, without the exact context, but that should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Well I have  the code I provided and it has 12 values, so the code is about 150 lines long. I wanted to refactor it, so it was smaller and just looped through 12 iterations and updated the value_ and the other variables that have _ in the name

Comment: OK. The thing I was questioning is why you have such variable in the first place? Why not have an array instead?

Comment: How would I do it via an array?

Comment: I presume that somewhere in your code, you assign the variables `value_1`, `value_2` ... Instead of doing this, make `value` an array and then push values to that array, rather than creating a new named variable to hold each value.Then the above code can replace your given example.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this one helps u...

```
$arrOutput = compact('text_1', 'text_2', 'text_3');
foreach($arrOutput as $t1)
{
    $out1[] = implode(",", $t1);
}
print_r($out1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should probably be using an array or map to hold the values and iterating over that, assuming that the values you're dealing with are all the same sort of thing.